# How To Change pivot and set to Center in yoyo lib Animation

Tags: android, animation, pivot, center

I have a problem with yoyo lib. when I run the project, Animation Rotate from top-left corner. I want change `.pivot()` and set to center pivot.
in fact I want Animation Rotation on the center pivot, as like Rotation Ball.
But I don't know how to change code.
Thanks for help.

My Code:

```
        YoYo.with(Techniques.RotateIn)
        .duration(2000)
        .pivot(float pivotX, float pivotY) //How to set parameters this line code?
        .playOn(my_view);
```

Answer (score 0):

The default pivot is:

```
 .pivot(YoYo.CENTER_PIVOT, YoYo.CENTER_PIVOT)
```

You can add a `GlobalLayoutListener` if your view is not loaded completely:

```
yourView.getViewTreeObserver().addOnGlobalLayoutListener (new ViewTreeObserver.OnGlobalLayoutListener() {
            @Override
            public void onGlobalLayout() {
                YoYo.with(Techniques.RotateIn)
                        .duration(2000)
                        .pivot(YoYo.CENTER_PIVOT, YoYo.CENTER_PIVOT)
                        .playOn(yourView);
            }
        });
```